# PNG Transparency in IE6 - Need help with "How to apply hack for stylesheet"

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to apply css for my table as show in sample "9.Table Background"  as given in the below link.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/

It is working finr in IE-7 and fire fox.

A comment for that sample is specified - " IE 6 users won’t see the transparent background if the hack is not applied ".

Can any one help me in applying the hack and make the sample work in ie-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hack is a work around for earlier versions of IE not supporting the alpha (transparency) channel in PNG images. Rather than steal the glory from others, I'll point you at some posts explaining this:

http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/11/css-png-image-fix-for-ie/

http://www.scriptingmagic.com/Topics/IE%20Specific/PNG%20Transparency/

Alternatively, google "IE6 PNG CSS HACK" for more...

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article on PNG opacity on a list apart.

http://www.alistapart.com/stories/pngopacity/

This JS script adds near-native PNG support with alpha opacity to IE 5.5 and 6.

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/